# Get just the name dynamically in a NET::IMAP:Address Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Hi I retrieved an Array from GMAIL API.

I want to record just the name of the receiver. I am pulling all sent emails into my app.

Here's the array that I retrieved:

```
[#<struct Net::IMAP::Address name="Shiela S", route=nil, mailbox="Shielas", host="test.com">]
```

I want to pass the receiver name into my `Activity` table . I already have the correct logic in passing values to my ActiveRecord but then how can I get just the name from the array above (dynamically).

I've tried to strip or split other unnecessary strings inside the array but no luck..

I want to end up having just the name which is `Shiela S` from the array above.

Any suggestions? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've tried to convert to string and it worked!

In string:

```
"[#<struct Net::IMAP::Address name=\"Shiela S\", route=nil, mailbox=\"Shielas\", host=\"test.com\">]"
```

Is there a better way than using `slice!` method to get the `Shiela S` substring?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `.name` on the [struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Struct.html)?

Comment: Yes, it says `NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x007f9e7b499690>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Struct you want to access is wrapped in an Array, probably because an email can be sent to multiple recipients. So, given

```
recipients = [#<struct Net::IMAP::Address name="Shiela S", route=nil, mailbox="Shielas", host="test.com">]
```

you should be able to do

```
recipients.first.name
```

to get the name of the first recipient, or

```
recipients.collect(&:name)
```

to get an array of the names of all the recipients.

Comment: Thank you. Wahhh my bad for doing a complex method. Thanks a lot!